# Can I launch a shell script from home screen?

Tags: shell

There's one tweak of my phone I'm applying/removing through two some pretty simple shell scripts. But going to terminal emulator and typing the script names each time aside, the tweak actually makes on-screen keyboard unusable and may necessitate adb access to start `deactivate.sh`

Is there a way to launch the scripts from the home screen - just place them as icons, the way you can just double-click a .bat file on your desktop on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**,
Download **terminal emulator** app from playstore.it gives the access to commands directly by using **Widgets**.through this you can place the widget in homescreen and launch a command in a 'click'.

Comment: Could you link the app? There are dozens of Terminal Emulators, and most don't provide that.